# Fetch the header of next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fetch the contents of div like header & other details on radio selected radio button.
I am doing like

```
$('input[name=subscription_plan_radio]:checked').parent().next('plan-info').html()
```

By doing this , I am able to fetch the contents of plan-info div, but I want to fetch the next h3 inside it.

so, I am trying `$('input[name=subscription_plan_radio]:checked').parent().next('plan-info h3').text()`

but it is giving a blank string.

below is the html code.

```
    <div class="plan-info">
      <h3>
        Pay Per Lead
       </h3>
       <div class="plan-details">
         <h4 class="price">
             $99
            <span>month</span>
         </h4>
         <ul class="features">
           <li>Buy Unsigned Leads</li>
           <li>Price per Category from $100 to 500</li>
           <li>Email Notification when a New Leads is available</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the radio button & which header you are referring?

Comment: where is this radio?

Comment: radio button is above this html & i want to fetch the h3 of plan-info div

Comment: Make a fiddle it will be helpful

Comment: Even better, do not make a fiddle. Make a snippet.

Comment: If radio button is above HTML then parent will not work. Can you please edit it and add the complete HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
$('input[name=subscription_plan_radio]:checked').parent().next('.plan-info').find('h3').text()
```

Comment: how can you use .parent() & next() without knowing the position of radio button in DOM?

Comment: He was looking for h3 inside plan-info div , as per his reference it can be fetched inside plan-info.

Comment: there is no radio button inside plan-info div, that is reason parents() and next() may not work

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where is your `checkbox`. But try with it.

```
$('input[name=subscription_plan_radio]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).checked){
        $('..plan-info').find('h3').text(); // Select only text Pay Per Lead
        $('..plan-info').find('h3').html(); // Select html <h3>Pay Per Lead</h3>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=subscription_plan_radio]:checked').parent().next().find('h3').html()
```

should work, assuming that your radio button is in a div just before the plan-info div.